# Fourier transform of $\sin(ax)$

Tags: calculus

I have been graphing and calculating the Fourier transform of some functions and not understanding the results.

I expected the FT of $\sin(3x)$ for $0 < x < 2\pi$ to have a single peak at a frequency of $3$. It is after all a pure note of frequency $3$. Instead I get two slightly separated high peaks; according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) that is correct - it is two dirac delta functions added together. As are $\sin(nx)$ for all $n > 1$. In my mind's eye (which is obviously as blind as a bat) the inverse FT of two Dirac delta functions is two notes of different frequencies.

I have this notion of the FT of the function being its representation in the frequency domain, but this example shows I'm missing something. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)$

There should be dirac delta function at $a$ and at $-a$.

Do $-a$ and $a$ really represent different prequencies?